# is onevent option ignored for jsf.ajax.request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I am trying to create an interactive chat web application using Java EE 7, in particular using JSF 2.2 with ajax.

The idea is that there is always one slow pending asynchronous ajax request waiting
on the server for each individual client. Once a new message arrives to the server,
all waiting requests are returned so that the messages are rendered in all clients.
On completion of the requests, new waiting requests are sent by the clients.
If no message arrives within 30 seconds, the request is returned so that a new one
can be submitted before the old one times out.

I could make it work like this:

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>async jsf app</title>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="resendscript.js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body> 

        async jsf app
        <h:form id="jsfappform">
            say something: 
            <h:inputText id="newmsg" value="#{jsfAsync.newMessage}" />
            <h:commandButton id="sendbut" value="say" action="#{jsfAsync.say}" />
            <br /><br />
            Messages:
            <br /><br />
            <h:outputText id="msgs" value="#{jsfAsync.msgs}" escape="false">
                <h:outputScript>resendRequest()</h:outputScript>
            </h:outputText>            
            <h:commandButton id="reloadbut" value="" action="#{jsfAsync.resend}" style="visibility: hidden">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="msgs" onevent="handleAjax" onerror="handleError" /> 
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton id="clearbut" value="clear" action="#{jsfAsync.clear}" />
            <h:outputScript>resendRequest()</h:outputScript>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

resendscript.js:

```
function handleAjax(data) 
{
    var status = data.status;
    switch(status) 
    {
        case "success": resendRequest();
                        break;
    }
}

function handleError(data) { }

function resendRequest() 
{
    document.getElementById("jsfappform:reloadbut").click();
}
```

backing bean JsfAsync.java:

```
package jsfasync;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class JsfAsync 
{
    private final List<String> messages;
    private final Object wakeup;

    public JsfAsync() 
    {
        wakeup = new Object();
        messages = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    }

    public void setNewMessage(String msg)
    {
        synchronized(messages)  {  messages.add(msg); }            
    }

    public void say()
    {  
        synchronized(wakeup)  {  wakeup.notifyAll();  }
    }

    public void resend()
    {         
        try { 
          synchronized(wakeup)  {  wakeup.wait(30000);  }
        } catch (Exception e) { }    
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        synchronized(messages)  {  messages.clear();  }
        say();
    }

    public String getNewMessage() {  return ""; }

    public String getMsgs()
    {
        StringBuilder msgs = new StringBuilder();
        synchronized(messages)
        {
            for (String m : messages)
            {
                msgs.append(m);
                msgs.append("<br />");
            }        
            return msgs.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the body of the **resendRequest()** javascript function with the ajax request API as follows:

```
jsf.ajax.request('jsfappform:reloadbut', null, 
                 {'javax.faces.behavior.event': 'action', 
                  'execute': 'jsfappform:reloadbut', 
                  'render': 'jsfappform:msgs', 
                  'onevent': 'handleAjax',
                  'onerror': 'handleError'});
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it work this way. The call can perform the ajax request, but it seems the **onevent** option was ignored, and the event handler was not called when this request completed. Do you, perhaps, have any hints how to make it work in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hints, check the generated HTML source of `<h:commandButton id="reloadbut">`. You'll see that JSF has generated it as `'onevent': handleAjax`. Indeed, as function reference instead of as a string.

Fix it accordingly:

```
jsf.ajax.request('jsfappform:reloadbut', null, 
                 {'javax.faces.behavior.event': 'action', 
                  'execute': 'jsfappform:reloadbut', 
                  'render': 'jsfappform:msgs', 
                  'onevent': handleAjax,
                  'onerror': handleError});
```